# How to Draw a rectangle around group of rows WPF Devexpress

Tags: c#, wpf, devexpress

I'm working with Devexpress gridcontrol and am trying to display "Ranges" in my data. Allowing users to define a continuous group of rows in the grid as an Accepted Range.

To display this I'd like to draw a colored border around each of the Ranges, as ranges can have overlaps and we are already using multiple cell background colors just changing cell colors doesn't fit the need.

If anyone knows how to accomplish this it would be greatly appreciated.

Edit:
Some clarification, I want to programatically do something like this:

[image]

The ranges are defined by user at runtime.

Comment: Is there a way to define in grids to only show bottom/left/right border? I was trying to use borders but each row would have its own border which looked terrible and didnt help when one record had more than one range associated.

Comment: BorderThickness="1,0,1,1"

Comment: I have added an image for some clarification on what I'm talking about.